# How to alias part of expression for find?

Tags: find, alias

I prefer regular expressions with `-regex` over the shell pattern syntax of `-name`. I also want to use the `posix-egrep` type, so I'd like to do something like

`alias find="find -regextype posix-egrep"`

but that is an error since the path has to come before the expression. However, the `-regextype` has to be first in the expressions (or before using `-regex` or `-iregex`).

I just want to alias or have a shell function `find` so that it works the same as usual, just ready to use `posix-regex` whenever I decide to use the `-regex` or `-iregex` option.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since the `find` arguments are positional a function would be a better solution.

```
find(){
  command find "$1" -regextype posix-egrep "${@:2}"
}
```

since you want to "overwrite" the original command you need to use the full path of `find` so that your new function doesn't create an infinite loop of calling itself.

by using a function instead of an alias we can use positional argument variables (`$1-$n`).  since you also might want to add other things to the end of your `find` we append the command with `${@:2}` which appends all but the first argument (your path) using array slicing.

Comment: Nice answer. I learned much more than just a quick fix. I didn't know about putting the full path, and I really like the "$1" ... "${@:2}" idiom for slipping something in the middle. Thanks!

Comment: Use `command find` instead of hardcoding the path of `find`

Comment: Note that it means that you can no longer do `find dir1 dir2 -name...`

Comment: `"${@:2}"` is ksh syntax also supported by bash and zsh. Portably, you'd do `file=$1; shift; command find "$file" .... "$@"`

Comment: Thanks for the warning, Stephane. I think I'll just use an `efind` function to avoid problems with the original find. Also, I wasn't aware of the `find dir1 dir2` syntax. I've always searched a single dir, so that's good to know.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
efind() (
  found=false
  for arg do
    if [ "$arg" = -regex ] && ! "$found"; then
      set -- "$@" -regextype posix-egrep
      found=true
    fi
    set -- "$@" "$arg"
    shift
  done
  exec find "$@"
)
```

To insert `-regex-type posix-egrep` before the first occurrence of `-regex`.